# Middleware between node.js and Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

Is it good idea to implement Middleware service/app between node.js app and browser?

For example:

```
Browser <----- [Middleware]  <---- [Node JS]
```

Node.js send json meta data to `Middleware` app and then it pass it to Browser (socket or HTTP). How can this be done and should I use something like RabbitMQ for passing data from `[Node JS]` to `[Middleware]` app?

`[Middleware]` could also be written in node.js

The reason I thought doing this because I don't want browser or public to know about `[Node JS]` app.

`[Node JS]` is for communicating between PBX Server externally via TCP socket in real time. If I didn't have `[Middleware]` then end user could DDOS attack [Node JS] directly which would impact real time communication between `[Node JS]` and PBX server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to make these architecture decisions, then it is good to include risk management. Technically speaking, this middleware can be implemented but the crutial question here is "Should you implement this".

First ask yourself what is probability that someone is going to make DDOS attack on your server? If chances are minimal than you don't need this middleware.

If the probability is high, then how much money you will lose if someone really makes DDOS attack on your server and how much time you need to defend yourself and to make your service available again?

Some general calculation is to calculate how much you earn during one minute/hour/day and then multiply that by time your service is going to be offline.

What your customers expectations are, and how many customers will use your service?

Are there are any other methods  you can implement in order to soften DDOS attack.

And finally, how your middleware is going to protect your from DDOS attack? You don't want to spend hours implementing your middleware without knowing it is really going to protect you. By making middleware, you are "masking" your Node.js server, but still someone can attack your middleware and make your service offline and then what?